# cmake: undefined reference to any pcap functions

Tags: c++, cmake, pcap

I want to use pcap in my Clion project on linux.
I installed libpcap-dev:

```
sudo apt-get install libpcap-dev
```

But then I try to compile any file, containing pcap functions like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pcap.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *dev, errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];

    dev = pcap_lookupdev(errbuf);
    if (dev == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't find default device: %s\n", errbuf);
        return(2);
    }
    printf("Device: %s\n", dev);
    return(0);
}
```

I have cmake errors:

```
CMakeFiles/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `pcap_lookupdev'
```

I have not used cmake before. Cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(mypr)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(mypr ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Comment: You're not linking to pcap. You'd get the exact same errors without CMake. You need an appropriate [`target_link_libraries()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) command.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should include and use a FindPCAP.cmake file to your CMakeLists.txt. Here is one: https://github.com/bro/cmake/blob/master/FindPCAP.cmake

Put FindPCAP.cmake in your project's source directory and try changing your CMakeLists.txt to:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(mypr)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

include(FindPCAP.cmake)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(mypr ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(mypr ${PCAP_LIBRARY})
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to use `find_package(PCAP REQUIRED)` instead of a direct `include(FindPCAP.cmake)` ?

Comment: If there is a FindPCAP.cmake in the default cmake path now, yes it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also use `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` (assume `FindPCAP.cmake` is in your project's source directory):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(mypr)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/")

find_package(PCAP REQUIRED)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(mypr ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(mypr ${PCAP_LIBRARY})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have encounted with a problem similar to this, when I tried to complied with libpcap by ros catkin_make

```
CMakeFiles/decode_pcap.dir/src/decode_pcap.cpp.o：在函数‘main’中：
decode_pcap.cpp:(.text+0x130)：对‘pcap_open_live’未定义的引用
decode_pcap.cpp:(.text+0x1b3)：对‘pcap_next’未定义的引用
decode_pcap.cpp:(.text+0x2a4)：对‘pcap_loop’未定义的引用
decode_pcap.cpp:(.text+0x2e6)：对‘pcap_close’未定义的引用
decode_pcap.cpp:(.text+0x2ff)：对‘pcap_close’未定义的引用
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

at last, I added the absolute path to "libpcap.so" by link_libraries() in CMakeLists.txt,like the below

```
link_libraries(/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcap.so.0.8)
```